# In Firefox table margins don't collapse

Tags: css, firefox, cross-browser, margin

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhhWd/) to demonstrate the problem. Table margins don't collapse in Firefox, whereas they do in Chrome and IE.

**Firefox**

[image: Table margins don't collapse in Firefox]

**Chrome and IE**

[image: Table margins collapse in Chrome and IE]

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: For what it's worth, this bug is fixed in Firefox 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firefox is not `collapsing vertical margin` with `table's` because http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/margin-collapse-tables

Write `display:block` in table like this:

```
section, div, table {
    margin: 1em;
    display:block;
}
```

Check this example http://jsfiddle.net/fhhWd/2/

Comment: But "display: block" makes another bug; check this out http://jsfiddle.net/fhhWd/5/